# Using RVM on FTP gives error "RVM is not a function..."

Tags: ruby, function, ftp, rvm

I'm logging in to a FTP server and using our own servers version of ruby and gemset:

```
rvm use 1.9.2@'...'
```

But I get the error:

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use...' will not work.
```

Do I add this: `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` to my `.bashrc`? Or what is the case here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT:** I've found that this only occurs when I'm running a 'screen' session on the server. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" && rvm use 1.9.2@gemset
```